# Play template only works when called with parentheses

Tags: scala, playframework

I have the following code in my `Application` controller:

```
  def index = Action {
    var ticketsAvailable = 1
    Ok(views.html.index)
  }
```

When I try to run the application, I get this compilation error:

```
Cannot write an instance of views.html.index.type to HTTP response. Try to define a Writeable[views.html.index.type]
```

On the line

```
Ok(views.html.index)
```

However, when I add parentheses (as shown below), the error disappears:

```
Ok(views.html.index())
```

Why is that?
I thought that, in Scala, the usage of parentheses is optional when there are no arguments.

Comment: You thought wrong. See http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html#parentheses

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might be instructive to look at the generated Scala code for a simple Twirl template (Twirl is the Play templating engine) called `index.scala.html`:

```
@()

<h1>Hello, world</h1>
```

By default, Play will compile this to a Scala file in `target/scala-2.11/twirl/main/views/html/index.template.scala`, and, if you clean it up a bit to remove source mappings (which enable compile errors in templates to be translated to the right line in the input file) it will look something like this:

```
package views.html
import play.twirl.api._

object index_Scope0 {
  import models._
  import controllers._
  import play.api.i18n._
  import views.html._
  import play.api.templates.PlayMagic._
  import play.api.mvc._
  import play.api.data._

  class index
    extends BaseScalaTemplate[play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable, Format[play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable]](play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat)
    with play.twirl.api.Template0[play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable] {

    def apply(): play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable = {
      _display_ {
        {
          Seq[Any](format.raw(""""""), format.raw("""<h1>hello, world</h1>"""))
        }
      }
    }

    def render(): play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable = apply()
    def f: (() => play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable) = () => apply()
    def ref: this.type = this
  }
}

object index extends index_Scope0.index
```

The important thing to note is that `views.html.index` is an *object*, which has the type `views.html.index.type`, and that's what you refer to if you don't add parens. This object, however, extends a class called `views.html.index_Scope0.index`, which has an `apply()` method, which returns an `Html` object (or rather, `HtmlFormat.Appendable`, which is the unaliased type.)

If you "call" a Scala object, Scala translates (or "de-sugars") that to calling the `apply()` method on the object (which is how case class constructors work without using `new`.) Hence, if you use parens you get an `Html` object which is the result of the rendered Twirl template. If you don't, you just get the compiled template object itself, which Play doesn't know how to write to an HTTP response.